# Typing Mathematica code

Tags: discussion, formatting

When I posted the piece of code : FourierTransform[u[x,y]+v[x,y],y,q], I got an answer advising me to improve the typeset of the code.
How can I type a Mathematica code while I'm posting a question here in StackEcchange?

Comment: You can type code either between backticks, or by pressing `Ctrl`+`K` (or equivalently by pressing the button with braces, or by indenting four spaces in general). The latter will display the code on a new line. For large piece of code, it is advised to use the last approach.

Comment: There's a [?] button on the editing toolbar.  Click it and formatting help comes up.

Comment: My boilerplate advice: "You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful."  The Meta tag [site-tools](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-tools) has lots of other helpful stuff.

Comment: I need to reformat my question? How? Should I repost  it again?

Comment: See the "edit" button at the bottom left corner of your post?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QG6Xi.png BTW, what's your first language?

Comment: @MichaelE2 are your  'boiler plate' comments in a repository on stackexchange, in a text file that you copy and paste from with or without some script/hot keys to facilitate or something else? I see many users have such well worded commonly used comments. I apologize for this basic question. I have never been organized enough to make my own or collect others (and then what is acceptable and how should attribution be specified succinctly). So, I resort to my own off the cuff (well intentioned but perhaps off the mark sometimes) comments.

Comment: @ubpdqn Related: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138/1871

Comment: @xzczd thank you! The link is very helpful :)

Comment: @ubpdqn I have a scratch notebook I use when browsing the site. I keep a few text cells at the top of it (and a few utility function definitions). I copy and paste them. I think it's possible to write a Javascript extension for them. Actually thinking about it, I could write a `comment["name"]` function with `CopyToClipboard`.  I'd just have to remember the comment names. My greeting boilerplate I adapted from belisarius; many users have similar variants. -- See this: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1896/